# How can I connect 2 classes with their Scanner variables in Java?

Tags: java, class, variables, java.util.scanner, string-matching

I'm trying to do `SignUp` and `LogIn` scripts. (username & password)

And I did them in 2 separate classes.

But I don't know to connect them.

I want the `SignUp` username to match the `LogIn` username and same to the password.

**Here's the SignUp Class:**

```
import java.util.*;

public class SignUp {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static String username;
    public static String password;

    public void vars(String username, String password) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public void usernameMethod() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Your Username:");
        username = input.next();
    }

    public void passMethod() {
        System.out.println("Your Password:");
        password = input.next();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("SIGN UP\n\n");
        SignUp Adam = new SignUp();
        Adam.vars(username, password);
        Adam.usernameMethod();
        Adam.passMethod();
        System.out.println("Signed Up Successfully!");
    }

}
```

**And Here's the LogIn Class:**

```
import java.util.*;

public class LogIn {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String username2 = null;
        String password2 = null;

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        SignUp signUp = new SignUp();

        signUp.vars(username2, password2);
        System.out.println("Your Username:");
        username2 = input.next();

        while (!username2.contentEquals(SignUp.username)) {
            System.out.print("That doesn't match our records! Try again.");
            username2 = input.next();
        }

        if (username2.contentEquals(SignUp.username)) {
            System.out.print("Your Password:");
            password2 = input.next();
            if (password2.contentEquals(SignUp.password)) {
                System.out.print("Enjoy the Game!");
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: 1) You're never calling `usernameMethod`, or `passMethod`, so those properties are never set. 2) Your variables shouldn't be static

Comment: but if variables aren't static it'll generate this error when i get the method= **(Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field password)**